sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "person" does not exist
I have the following error when I want to insert or query a model with the structure shown in the image
I working with postgres and alembic for migraciones, the table with error already exist, why execute migration
This is my code of conection
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker ,declarative_base

from database.base import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL


DATABASE_URL = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL,pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=20, max_overflow=30)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

Table person
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "persons"

    id = Column("id",Integer, primary_key=True, index=True,autoincrement=True)
    name = Column("name",String(50))
    email = Column("email",String(50))

And execute migration alembic revision --autogenerate -m "create table" and alembic upgrade head
def validateExistPerson(db: Session, name: str) -> bool:
    existPerson = getPersonByName(db, name)
    if not existPerson:
        return False
    return True

route
@person_router.post(
    '/add',
    tags=["Person"],
    response_model=Person,
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
)
async def addPerson(person: Person, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    existPerson = validateExistPerson(db, person.name)
    if existPerson:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail="Name person already exist")
    
    result = createPerson(person, db)
    
    if result:
        return result
    
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail="Error to create person")

when call validateExistPerson show error
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "persons" does not exist
test_srit  | LINE 2: FROM persons 
test_srit  |              ^
test_srit  | 
test_srit  | [SQL: SELECT persons.id AS persons_id, persons.name AS persons_name, persons.email AS persons_email 
test_srit  | FROM persons 
test_srit  | WHERE persons.name = %(name_1)s 
test_srit  |  LIMIT %(param_1)s]
test_srit  | [parameters: {'name_1': 'maria gomez', 'param_1': 1}]
test_srit  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)



Looks like the table does not exist in the database.  Can you include the code you used to create the database?  Also can you verify that you checked that the table exists manually via a command line tool, like psql?  Otherwise you might have to reduce your example into something more reproduce-able for others.

Did you intend to have SQLAlchemy create the database for you, or are you trying to describe an existing database?

You'll have to call create_all (with an empty database) to create your tables https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all - or use alembic to create the initial migration from an empty database, and then migrations between different versions of your database. https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/


DO NOT use images for textual data, copy and paste as text update to question text. 2) Is the table name actually person or is some upper/mixed case version. As examples:  Person or PERSON


@IanWilson yes, if it validates that the database exists in the table, after executing the migration

Already solution the error Adding

Already solution the error Adding Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) in files
database.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker ,declarative_base

from database.base import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL


DATABASE_URL = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL,pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=20, max_overflow=30)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

